# Finding leaf nodes in is_a() Tree in Prolog

Tags: tree, prolog, nodes

I have made a basically a 'tree' in 'prolog' using `is_a(X, Y)'. Which looks something like this:

```
is_tree('b', 'a').
is_tree('c', 'a').
is_tree('d', 'b').
is_tree('e', 'b').
is_tree('f', 'c').
is_tree('g', 'c').

       a
  b         c
d   e      f  g
```

And now I am trying to find all the leaf nodes, which would be `d, e, f, g`. 
So far I have succeeded in `write()'ing` out the 1st leaf but I do not understand how I should go back up the tree to find the other nodes and how I should write my `closing clause` to find the values.

```
find_leaf(X, Y):-
    \+is_tree(X, Y).
find_leaf(X, Y):-
    is_tree(A, Y), !,
    find_leaf(Y, A).
find_leaf(X, Y):-
    is_tree(A, X),
    write(Y),
    find_leaf(Y, A).
```

How can I go "back up again" to find the other leaves? And what would be the correct "closing sentence"?

Comment: What are `X` and `Y` doing here?

Comment: Well I did not name them, but they can be anything. It is just something I used to find the leaves. One of them is pretty irrelevant but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it so I took more variables hoping that would help me.

Comment: but I think this is a bit the wrong approach. Typically you define predicates where the variables have a certain *meaning*, then you aim to implement the "body" of the predicate by calling predicates with these variables such that it is consistent with that purpose.

Comment: Well initially I thought that this could be solved by using only `root` but well, I am still stuck.

Comment: What is `root` here?

Comment: Here it would be `Y`

Comment: A better name for `is_tree` would be `is_child_node`. How would you define a leaf? A leaf is a node that has no children. There are two conditions in that statement if you formalize it: *`N` is a leaf node **if** `N` is a node and `N` has no children.*. If you express that in Prolog, you'd get `leaf_node(N) :- is_child_node(N, _), \+ is_child_node(_, N).`. Of course your date does not allow the representation of a tree that consists only of one node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most predicate's in Prolog do not `write/1` things. Just like in imperative, and functional programming typically a large number of functions *calculate* things, and others then "communicate" things (by writing to the console, changing the user interface, etc.

So I would propose to construct a predicate `find_leaf(X)` that unifies the variable `X` with a leaf. Due to Prolog's backtracking mechanism, we can then end up unifying with all the leaves.

## Obtaining nodes from the `is_tree/2` predicate

Here the nodes - unless you did not mention this - can only be obtained by analyzing the `is_tree/2` predicate where the first item is the "child" and the second item the "parent". We know here something is a leave if it is a node, and not a parent. Since there are no other mechanisms to define the tree, a node is (likely) a child in some `is_tree` predicate.

We thus can implement a predicate that finds childs with:

```
find_leave(X) :-
    is_tree(X, _),
    \+ is_tree(_, X).
```

So the first call `is_tree(X, _)` will unify `X` with a child in the tree, whereas the second call verifies that there is no child for `X`.

This then yields:

```
?- find_leave(X).
X = d ;
X = e ;
X = f ;
X = g.
```

## Obtain leaves from a given root

We can also pass the root through a parameter, for example: `find_leave(b, X)` will unify `X` with all childs of `b`. We here make two cases:

1. `R`, the root, is not a parent, in that case `R = X` (`R` is a leave); and
2. otherwise if there are children, we recursively call `find_leave(C, X)` with `C` a child. Due to backtracing eventually we will obtain all leaves.

So:

```
find_leave(R, R) :-
    \+ is_tree(_, R).
find_leave(R, X) :-
    is_tree(C, R),
    find_leave(C, X).
```

We then thus obtain for different roots, different leaves:

```
?- find_leave(a, X).
X = d ;
X = e ;
X = f ;
X = g ;
false.

?- find_leave(b, X).
X = d ;
X = e ;
false.

?- find_leave(R, X).
R = a,
X = d ;
R = a,
X = e ;
R = a,
X = f ;
R = a,
X = g ;
R = b,
X = d ;
R = b,
X = e ;
R = c,
X = f ;
R = c,
X = g ;
false.
```

Comment: Looking at the first answer I think I might not have understood prolog correctly. How is `find_leave(X)` find all leaves and calling itself again with no recursion?

Comment: @kataroty: it enumerates over the `is_tree(X, _).` predicate so `X` will eventually get unified with *all* childs in the tree (these can be inodes as well), but then our `\+ is_tree(_, X)` is satisfied given no *child* of `X` exists.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again and ignore me if you are busy but with this method there is no way to count how many leaves we have right?

Comment: @kataroty: there is, you just use it in a `findall/3`, and then calculate the length, so `findall(L, find_leave(L), Ls), length(Ls, N)` will unify `N` with the number of leaves.